# Caramel/Crystal malts and Steeping

Tags: steeping, crystal, grain

Does any grain/malt that's name begins with "Caramel" or "Crystal" mean it is able to be steeped to extract the aroma, color and flavor?

I am referring to grain/malts like Carapils, Caramunich, Caravienne, Carahell, Crystal Rye, Crystal Wheat, etc...

I am only able to do partial mashes with extracts at this time, but I don't want to be limited in styles I can produce and flavors I can get from specialty grains.

Answer (score 2):

## In general, yes.

In this month's issue of BYO (Vol. 16 No. 2) Bob Hansen, Manager of Technical Services at Briess Malt, warns:

> "... some American malt marketed as caramel, or crystal, malts are actually produced on a kiln and are only partially converted. These can be identified by cracking the kernels. If mealy starch is discovered in many of the kernels, the product was produced on a kiln or blended and will require conversion in a mash."